# Proof Weyl's theorem for singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Could anyone provide a reference to Proof of Weyl's theorem for singular values ?

If $X$ and $Y$ are $m\times n$ ($m\geq n$) and the singular values are ordered in the decreasing order, we have

$$σ_{i+j−1}^{(X+Y)} ≤ σ_i^{(X)}+σ_j^{(Y)} \text { for } 1≤i,j≤n,i+j−1≤n.$$

I have the following reference which proves it for eigen values for Hermitian matrices. But I am not sure how to extend it to singular values.
[https://www.math.drexel.edu/~foucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect5.pdf](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Efoucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect5.pdf)

Comment: You can see a proof in this blog post, it follows from the variational characterization of singular values: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/singular-value-decomposition/

Comment: Thanks a lot @QiaochuYuan